# How to filter the items in a DataFrame based on a list in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list, filter

I am new to coding and am trying to work on the following data:

```
df=
    Position
    A/C MECHANIC
    A/C TECHNICIAN
    A/C TECHNICIAN HELPER
    ACCOUNTANT
    ACCOUNTANT MANAGER
    ACCOUNTING CLERK
    ACCOUNTS AUDITOR
    ACCOUNTS MANAGER
    ACCOUNTS SUPERVISOR
    ACTING HOSPITAL ADMINISTRATOR
    ADMINISTRATION SECRETARY
    ADMINISTRATIVE  SUPERVISOR
    ADMINISTRATIVE CLERK
    ADMINISTRATIVE COORDINATOR
    ADMINISTRATIVE DIRECTOR
    ADMINISTRATIVE MANAGER
    ADMINISTRATOR OF MED.INSURANCE
    ADMINSTRATION OFFICE MANAGER
    ADMISSION COUNTER CLERK
    ADMISSION OFFICER
```

I have the following list:

```
name=['TECHNICIAN', 'MANAGER', 'CLERK', 'AUDITOR', 'SUPERVISOR', 'SECRETARY', 'COORDINATOR', 'DIRECTOR', 'OFFICER', 'SPECIALIST', 'PROGRAMMER', 'TYPIST', 'LIASON', 'DESIGNER', 'ENGINEER', 'ACCOUNTANT', 'ADMINISTRATOR', 'BAKER', 'COOK']
```

I am trying to create a new dataframe where It takes the values from the above mentioned list finds the corresponding position that contains that word and then adds it to a column in a new dataframe.

Here is the code I am using.

```
newdf=pd.DataFrame()
for i in name:
  print(i)
  newdf[i]=df[df['position'].str.contains(i)]
```

I am trying to add each and every filtered value to a new column in the "newdf".

When I am running the above code i am getting this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series
```

I am trying to get the following output:

```
TECHNICIAN,              MANAGER,
A/C TECHNICIAN           ACCOUNTANT MANAGER
ALUMINUM TECHNICIAN      ACCOUNTS MANAGER
ANAESTHESIA TECHNICIAN   ADMINISTRATIVE MANAGER
APPLIANCE TECHNICIAN    
BIOMEDICAL SENIOR   
BIOMEDICAL TECHNICIAN   
BOILER TECHNICIAN   
COMPUTER TECHNICIAN 
COMPUTER TECHNICIAN 
COMPUTER TECHNICIAN
```

Comment: Please add expected output.

Comment: @HenryYik I added the expected output. thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create dictionary of `DataFrame`s and pass to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
dfs = {i: df.loc[df['Position'].str.contains(i), 'Position'].reset_index(drop=True) 
           for i in name}
newdf = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

---

```
print (newdf)
                 TECHNICIAN                           MANAGER  \
0             A/C TECHNICIAN                ACCOUNTANT MANAGER   
1      A/C TECHNICIAN HELPER                  ACCOUNTS MANAGER   
2                        NaN            ADMINISTRATIVE MANAGER   
3                        NaN      ADMINSTRATION OFFICE MANAGER   

                         CLERK               AUDITOR  \
0             ACCOUNTING CLERK      ACCOUNTS AUDITOR   
1         ADMINISTRATIVE CLERK                   NaN   
2      ADMISSION COUNTER CLERK                   NaN   
3                          NaN                   NaN   

                       SUPERVISOR                     SECRETARY  \
0             ACCOUNTS SUPERVISOR      ADMINISTRATION SECRETARY   
1      ADMINISTRATIVE  SUPERVISOR                           NaN   
2                             NaN                           NaN   
3                             NaN                           NaN   

                      COORDINATOR                     DIRECTOR  \
0      ADMINISTRATIVE COORDINATOR      ADMINISTRATIVE DIRECTOR   
1                             NaN                          NaN   
2                             NaN                          NaN   
3                             NaN                          NaN   

                 OFFICER SPECIALIST PROGRAMMER TYPIST LIASON DESIGNER  \
0      ADMISSION OFFICER        NaN        NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN   
1                    NaN        NaN        NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN   
2                    NaN        NaN        NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN   
3                    NaN        NaN        NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN   

  ENGINEER              ACCOUNTANT                       ADMINISTRATOR BAKER  \
0      NaN              ACCOUNTANT       ACTING HOSPITAL ADMINISTRATOR   NaN   
1      NaN      ACCOUNTANT MANAGER      ADMINISTRATOR OF MED.INSURANCE   NaN   
2      NaN                     NaN                                 NaN   NaN   
3      NaN                     NaN                                 NaN   NaN   

  COOK  
0  NaN  
1  NaN  
2  NaN  
3  NaN
```

---

```
newdf.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: @jazrael when I am using this its not filtering anything but giving me the "df" again.

Comment: I just updated my question with the output i am trying to get

Comment: I tried both the codes unfortunately I am getting the "df" as my output

Comment: this works mate. but instead of creating a new list can you help with with getting a new DataFrame.

Comment: This is really good. thanks a lot. but i am trying to create a csv file with the coloumn names as the items in the list(name) and in each of the coloumn it should have the values that contain those words. Thanks a lot for helpiong

Comment: @rzee1991 - Last add `newdf.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)`, asnwer was edited.

Comment: Amazing.. Thanks aLOOOTT